# How to change the width of an Android ImageView in XML keeping aspect ratio?

Tags: android, xml, imageview

Can I set value for the width of Android ImageView in XML without changing its original initial ratio?

I solved this problem in java but I can't do the same in Android XML.

[image: Description]

What I tried so far:

```
int width = (inital width);
int height = (inital height);
int fixedWidth = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels >> 1; 
int fixedHeight = (fixedWidth * height ) / (width); // 50% width of screen
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(fixedWidth, fixedHeight);
imageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add attribute in your imageView

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

and wrap-content your height, this way your height will be in aspect ratio